# How to open one dialog- box from multiple buttons on the same html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Div with class ="front" is clone more than once on a html page ,button nested (class=poperbtn) clone as well, the button use is to open dialog-box/pop up (class="poper"), for example : if I have 4 divs -> class=front which means 4 buttons -> class="poperbtn", everytime I click on one of these buttons the dialog-box must pop-up, how to do this? is it possible? here is a code example.

//Dialog - box open button

```
<div  class="front">
      <input type="button" class="poperbtn" value="push it!" />  </div>
```

// Div for Dialog box

```
<div id="poper"> <h1>here I am </h1></div>
```

//To avoid using id I select button (id=poperbtn) this way - works fine I got id="poperbtn" button .

```
var _btnToDialog = "";
        $(".front").live("click", function () {                    
            _btnToDialog = $(this).next().children().eq(0);           
        });
```

//Dialog box Jquery function - I am not sure about this code.. got stuck here..

```
$(function () {
            $("#poper").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 650,
                height: 600,
            });
            $(_btnToDialog).click(function () {
                $("#poper").dialog("open");
            });
        });
    });
```

**According to comments,I changed the button - has no Id only class.

Comment: Id should be unique in a html page. Classes can be repeated. Switch your button id to class.

Comment: even better use `data-` attributes as js hooks - leave `class` for what's intended for: css presentation

Comment: @topless - ok If  I will remove Id and use classes what is my next step  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can hang click handler for all `input` inside `.front` elements.
- Due to dynamically created elements it should be, for example

  ```
  $(document).on("click", "selector", function() {})
  ```

instead of

```
    $("selector").click(function() {})
```

So finally code will look like:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".front input", function() {
        $("#poper").dialog("open");
    });
```

- You can add class (for example, `.button`) for required `input`s. Then code can be simplified to:

  ```
  $(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
      $("#poper").dialog("open");
  });
  ```
- **Update**. With `input`s class `.poperbtn` it will be

  ```
  $(document).on("click", ".poperbtn", function() {
      $("#poper").dialog("open");
  });
  ```

Comment: Well it looks nice but in the full code inside div[class=front] -> there are more inputs. So according to this info what to do next?

Comment: @Damkulul you're welcome. You can forget about `_btnToDialog` and about deprecated `.live()` aswell :) `this` points to clicked input's element inside `function()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/huhotu/8/edit?html,js,output) solution. There are many ways you can approach this problem it depends on what the desired behavior is you want to provide and the way you have already things in your codebase.